# What is the ServletFilter equalent of a RabbitMq Listener?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a `spring-boot` web application for which I implemented an `MDCFilter` that adds a `UUID` to `MDC` logging context that i can find in the log file.

The `Filter` class looks like this.

```
public class MDCFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    MDC.put(REQUEST_ID_KEY, requestId);
    response.addHeader("trace", requestId);
    try {
      chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    } finally {
      MDC.remove("trace");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

But recently we moved towards processing traffic via Queues and I have no clue from the documents to replicate this filter behaviour for the message listeners.

My listener would look something like this.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue1}")
public void receiveMessages(Message message) {
doTheBusinessLogic(message)
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the container's `adviceChain`. Assuming you are using Boot 2.0 and the simple container factory, override boot's factory to add the advice...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49770881Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49770881Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setAdviceChain(new MDCAdvice());
        return factory;
    }

    public static class MDCAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            // pre process
            try {
                return invocation.proceed();
            }
            finally {
                // post process
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I love this answer and I'm accepting it. But is there a way to add this Advice without manually creating a `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`. I feel that its clean to give that part to spring based on just properties files...

Comment: It would be tricky to autoconfigure the advice chain by type since `Advice` is a very general interface that might be used in multiple places. I suppose it could be a simple property `...advice-chain=foo,bar` where foo and bar are bean names. I don't know if the boot team would be receptive to that, but there is a precendent with `spring.jmx.server=mbeanServer # MBeanServer bean name.`. You could try opening an issue against boot to see what those guys think.

Comment: if i throw a runtime exception from inside an advice (like this MDCAdvice) is it like i throw it from inside the listener method ? I mean : is a NACK returned to rabbitmq ? Is the transaction rolled back if the listener is transactional ?  Thank you in advance @GaryRussell

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it doesn't help others. Asking a new question that references this answer is better. The answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell I posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75312685/rabbitmq-listener-exception-consequences-in-listener-interceptors-advices ...