# Spring Integration: AroundAdvice for AmqpInboundChannelAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I get AMQP-Messages from AmqpInboundChannelAdapter and send them further with WebServiceGateway. It is synchronous flow that runs in one thread.
I will add some slf4j additional logging information with static MDC fields.
It is a map object saved per thread and it should be cleaned after flow ends.
So how can I add AroundAdvice to an InboundChannelAdapter with java config?

```
AmqpInboundChannelAdapter 
          AroundAdvice
             // add MDC info before flow invocation
             MDC.put("orderNr", "someOrderNr");

             // flow execution with logs containing structured orderNr info

             // after flow execution do cleanup
             MDC.clean();

public void customerFlow(MessageProducerSupport amqpInboundChannelAdapter) throws Exception {
    IntegrationFlows
            .from(amqpInboundChannelAdapter)
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(MyEntity.class))
            .transform(entityToWsRequestTransformer)
            .handle(webServiceOutboundGateway)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter` can be created using an `Amqp.inboundAdapter()` Java DSL factory. And that one suggest us an option like:

```
.configureContainer(c -> c.adviceChain(...)))
```

There you can use your `AroundAdvice` and that is applied exactly for the `actualInvokeListener(Channel channel, Message message)` method, where sending message to the channel is performed.

Comment: Also see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770881/what-is-the-servletfilter-equalent-of-a-rabbitmq-listener).

Comment: Thank you Artem and Gary. Spring-Integration has best possible support because of you both.