# Throwing exceptions in RabbitMQ listener interceptors (advices)

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've a listener like the following :

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${myQueue}")
public void receiveMessages(Message message) {
   doTheBusinessLogic(message)
}
```

I understand from here
[What is the ServletFilter equalent of a RabbitMq Listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770881/what-is-the-servletfilter-equalent-of-a-rabbitmq-listener)

that we can execute some logic before getting inside the listener (an 'interceptor'), using Advice :

see the following code :

```
 @Bean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setAdviceChain(new MDCAdvice());
        return factory;
    }
```

So my question is : if i throw a runtime exception from inside an advice (like this MDCAdvice) is it like i throw it from inside the listener method ?

```
 public static class MDCAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            // pre process
            if (throwBefore) throw new RuntimeException("before")
            try {
                return invocation.proceed();
            }
            finally {
             // post process
            throw new RuntimeException("after")

            }
        }

    }
```

I mean : is a NACK returned to rabbitmq ? Is the transaction rolled back if the
listener is transactional ?

In general, is totally equivalent to throw it inside the doTheBusinessLogic(message) above ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; any exception thrown in the advice(s) will cause the same behavior as if the exception was thrown in the listener itself.

For example, if you want to discard a message, throw a `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

You can achieve the same by using a `MessagePostProcessor` (in the `afterReceivePostProcessors` and return `null`.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell. However, I noticed that if an exception is thrown from inside the listener method it is wrapped in a ListenerExecutionFailedException, instead if it is thrown by an Advice or a MessaProcessor (afterReceive) it is not wrapped and this has repercussions on the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler. Could it be okay to customize ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler ? Or am I doing something wrong? In the advices i check headers of the message...(if is duplicated..and put headers in MDC context)

Comment: It is probably easiest to wrap the real exception in an LEFE in the advice.

Comment: Thank You very much. In the meantime I had come to the same conclusion !